# ngclick with expression in ngrepeat doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use ngclick to navigate but for some reason when I use an expression inside ngclick the method doesn't get run.

code from a template that doesn't run go:

```
<ul id = "{{list.id}}" class = "list" >
    <li ng-repeat = "li in list.items" ng-click="go('/{{li.id}}')">
        <span>{{li.name}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

code from a template that does run go:

```
<ul id = "{{list.id}}" class = "list" >
    <li ng-repeat = "li in list.items" ng-click="go('/1')">
        <span>{{li.name}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Code from a controller:

```
$scope.go = function (path) {
    alert(path);
    //$location.path(path);
};
```

I'm hoping someone can point out where this is going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use delimiters when specifying variable-based arguments for `ng-click`; this should work:

```
<li ng-repeat = "li in list.items" ng-click="go('/' + li.id)">
```

But actually I'd rather have that `/` prepending code included into `go` function - or just create another function, `goToRoot`, with that functionality. This way it'll be easier to modify if your base path is changed, first, and it'll simplify the template, second.

Answer (score 1):

just use as follows; ngclick do not need templating

```
ng-click="go('/'+li.id)"
```